# How do I get superscript in tinytex data.table()

Tags: r, data.table, superscript

I am printing tables - in PDFs - by using `data.table()`. In these tables, I want some texts with superscript. I've tried a couples of things, but I only find solutions which are using `kable()` or `tibble()` - but I really want to use `data.table()` or solutions which are using `expression()` - which I cannot get working in PDFs.

Here is some simple example code.

```
library(data.table)

some_table <- data.table(
    element = c('Some text with <1> in superscript at the end',
                'Some more text')
    )
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your probably need a LaTeX command`$^1$`.. there is also `\superscript{}` I think.

Comment: @sindri_baldur: do you have a working example? I am unable to correctly implement your suggestions.

Comment: did you try my working example?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't resolve my issue. It just printed the input text without making superscript.

Comment: Ok. So you are not using Rmarkdown to print to PDF but something else?

Comment: I am using Rmarkdown (with tinytex). This is my output:
  pdf_document:
    df_print: kable
    includes:
      in_header: header.tex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sup` for superscript and `sub` for subscript. Maybe you want something like this:

```
library(DT)
some_table <- datatable(
  data.frame(c(1, 2), 
             row.names = c("Some text with A<sup>1</sup>", "Some more text")), rownames = T, escape = FALSE)

some_table
```

Output:

[image]

## Not supported with data.table

It seems like that superscripts expressions are not supported with the `data.table` package. You get the following error when trying:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(x, i, , ) : Internal error: column type 'expression' not supported by data.table subset. All known types are supported so please report as bug.
```

When using this code:

````
library(data.table)

    my_string <- "'title'^2"
    my_title <- parse(text=my_string)
    
    some_table <- data.table(
        element = c('Some text with', my_title, 'in superscript at the end',
                    'Some more text')
        )
    
    some_table
    ```

It seems currently not available for `data.table`.
````

Comment: I use data.table's data.table() instead of DT's datatable(). How can I get superscript in data.table()? Moreover, it gives me the following error. "Error: Functions that produce HTML output found in document targeting latex output.
Please change the output type of this document to HTML." However, I want PDF's, not HTML.

Comment: @JohnDoedel, I edited my answer. It seems it is not possible to use superscripts in text elements in `data.table`. I would suggest using a different format which does support superscript elements.

Comment: I accepted this answer seems - at this moment - it looks like it is not possible to use superscript in data.table().

Answer (score 0):

Two options with Rmarkdown + LaTeX:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r}
library(kableExtra)
levels(iris$Species)[1] <- "setosa\\textsuperscript{*}"
names(iris)[5]          <- "Species$^x$"
kable(iris[1:2, ], format='latex', escape=FALSE)
```
````

[image]